# How to Get a Value From Outer Join Table (more than 2 table) in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, outer-join, correlated-subquery

Im trying to get a value from outer join table but didnt work.. Need ur help..

1)Assume Tbl_report as below

```
   RID    |  CAT_ID  |  EXT_CODE
---------------------------------- 
    1     |    C01   |   HW06  
    2     |    C02   |   SW04 
    3     |    C03   |   IT04 
    4     |    C04   |   HW04 
    5     |    C05   |   SW02
```

WHERE **EXT_CODE** @ Tbl_report above is **referring from more than 1 table** (column **SCODE** from Tbl_SW, column **HCODE** from Tbl_HW or column **ICODE** from Tbl_IT) then, display the **content** of referrence table (which is content from column **SNAME** from Tbl_SW, **HNAME** from Tbl_HW or **INAME** from Tbl_IT)

2)Tbl_SW

```
   SID   |  SCODE   |  SNAME 
----------------------------------- 
     1   |   SW02   |   SEC 2  
     2   |   SW04   |   SEC 4
     3   |   SW06   |   SEC 6
```

3)Tbl_HW

```
   HID   |  HCODE   |  HNAME 
-----------------------------------
     1   |   HW02   |   HOC 2  
     2   |   HW04   |   HOC 4
     3   |   HW06   |   HOC 6
```

4)Tbl_IT

```
   IID   |  ICODE   |  INAME 
----------------------------------- 
     1   |   IT02   |   ITC 2  
     2   |   IT04   |   ITC 4
     3   |   IT06   |   ITC 6
```

Expected result as below :

```
   RID    |  CAT_ID  |  EXT_CODE
---------------------------------- 
    1     |    C01   |   HW06 - [HOC 6]
    2     |    C02   |   SW04 - [SEC 4]
    3     |    C03   |   IT04 - [ITC 4]
    4     |    C04   |   HW04 - [HOC 4]
    5     |    C05   |   SW02 - [SEC 2]
```

Comment: Hi @simon, can you show us what you expect to get ? The result - how will that look ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @VBokšić, i was update my expected result above.. tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this select statement

```
SELECT
`[RID]`,
`[CAT_ID]`,
CONCAT(`[EXT_CODE]`, ' - ',
`[SNAME]` ) result

FROM 
  Tbl_report tr 
  LEFT join   (SELECT * FROM Tbl_SW  UNION SELECT * FROM Tbl_HW UNION SELECT * FROM Tbl_IT) ts
  ON tr.`[EXT_CODE]` = ts.`[SCODE]`
```

You get  this result

```
RID     CAT_ID  result
1       C01     HW06 - HOC 6
2       C02     SW04 - SEC 4
3       C03     IT04 - ITC 4
4       C04     HW04 - HOC 4
5       C05     SW02 - SEC 2
```

DBfiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f78a88f019df887666ac059d39ba1f48

This work because your tables to join have teh same structure.

Left join i put there because in your first example you had it03 in it

Comment: It works under all Databsesystem Mysql doesn't like the brackets, there are more a ms sql style, I added the backticks, so that also mysql doesn't mind

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
Tbl_report.RID,   Tbl_report.CAT_ID,   Tbl_report.EXT_CODE,     Tbl_SW.SID,    
Tbl_SW.SNAME ,    Tbl_HW.HID    ,Tbl_HW.HNAME,    Tbl_IT.IID,  Tbl_IT.INAME

FROM (((Tbl_report
INNER JOIN Tbl_SW ON Tbl_Report.EXT_CODE=Tbl_SW.SCODE)
INNER JOIN Tbl_Hw ON Tbl_Report.EXT_CODE = Tbl_HW.HCODE)
INNER JOIN Tbl_IT ON Tbl_Report.EXT_CODE=Tbl_IT.ICODE);
```